# bootstrap tooltip not working on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do to Bootstrap tooltip on mouse hover on an input field of a form but it's not working. If you click on the input field, it shows the tooltip. However, I want it show on mouse hover and hide after 5 seconds. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UyJAZ/1/). This is the Javascript code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#number").popover({
        title: 'Enter Mobile Number', 
        content: "Please enter 10 digit mobile number prefixed by country code eg +911234567890"
    });  
});
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle is empty for me...

Comment: @RohanKumar please see now http://jsfiddle.net/UyJAZ/1/

Comment: @JoshuaSmock please see this http://jsfiddle.net/UyJAZ/1/

Comment: @javaBeginner check my solution out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide attribute `data-trigger`:

```
data-trigger="hover"
```

Try something like this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UyJAZ/3/)

```
<input type="text" name="toNumber" id="number" maxlength="13" placeholder="Enter 10 digits number to send" value="+917676462182" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover"/>
```

Comment: well can you please tell me what is data-trigger="hover"

Comment: @javaBeginner Set the trigger option of the popover to hover.This can be done using either data-* attributes in the markup:

Comment: thanks again,+1 for this.Well is it possible to hide the tooltip after some time say 5 secs

Comment: I used this way <input type="text" name="toNumber" id="number" maxlength="13" placeholder="Enter 10 digits number to send" value="+917676462182" rel="popover" data-delay='{"show":"10", "hide":"3000"}'/> but its not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39800/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-rajesh-kakawat)

Answer (score 3):

To make the popover work on hover, you have to use the `trigger: 'hover'` method available to the popover. You can also add a delay by adding the `delay` attribute. For example:

```
$(function () { 
    $("#number").popover({
        title: 'Enter Mobile Number', 
        content: "Please enter 10 digit mobile number prefixed by country code eg +911234567890",
        trigger: 'hover',
        delay: {show: 0, hide: 3000}
    });  
});
```

This will show your popover on hover on `#number` as well as add delay. See my updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UyJAZ/7/) as well. For a full description of the properties, visit [the Bootstrap docs on `popover`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Note that in the jsFiddle, it obscures part of the top of the popover. If the input is moved further down the page, the popover will display correctly.

Comment: Thanks its working,well I am foloowing this http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-tutorial.php So here they not have included trigger:'hover' but atill its working

Comment: They might be doing what @rajesh kakawat describes below, which is add `data-trigger="hover"` to the DOM element. This will also make the popover trigger on hover. Bootstrap reads `data-trigger="hover"` the same way it reads `trigger: 'hover'` in the Javascript code, by making the trigger for the popover `hover`.

Comment: I have given +1 because your answer is useful.Well are there any advantages of using data-trigger='hover' over trigger:'hover'

Comment: In theory, defining `trigger: 'hover'` might give you some performance gain since Bootstrap won't need to read the DOM, but in practice it's the same. The only real difference is style - if you want to define all of your attributes in the DOM, use the `data-*` attributes for the popover. If you want to keep all of your popover definition in your Javascript file, use the method I posted. It's up to you.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to hide the tooltip after 3 secs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39801/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-joshua-smock)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **trigger:'hover'** like,

```
$(function () {
    $("#number").popover({
        title: 'Enter Mobile Number',
        content: "Please enter 10 digit mobile number prefixed by country code eg +911234567890",
        trigger:'hover'
    });
});
```

Read [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/LWwr9/)

Comment: you gave the jsffidle for button and its working on click but I want it on input field and on hover.Please this http://jsfiddle.net/UyJAZ/1/ .here also its working on mouse click

Comment: @javaBeginner See my demo once again or http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/LWwr9/

Comment: Thanks its working now,+1 for that.Well please tell me you used trigger:'hover' and rajesh used data-trigger='hover' and this site is **not using** both http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-tutorial.php

Answer (score 1):

Just select your element, then call popover with hover

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Your Content">Mouse Over Here</a>

$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({trigger:"hover"});
```